# Angularjs controller name in application config vs ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with scope variables.Here is the cases;

Case 1 : Specifying controller name in html with ng-controller tag.In this case alert prints input variable.

```
   <ion-view view-title=“TEST”>
      <ion-content ng-controller=‘TestController’>

       <input name="aaa" id="dsds" ng-model="aaa" type="text"/>
            <h3>{{aaa}}</h3>

              <button class="button" ng-click=“test()”>Test</button>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>

   //CONTROLLERS//
    $scope.test = function(sql){
        var x = $scope.aaa;
        alert(x);
    };
```

Case 2 : when I define controller in config , The following alerts “undefined”

```
state('app.test’, {
     url: ‘/test’,

     views: {
       'menuContent': {
      controller: 'TestController',
         templateUrl: 'templates/programs/test.html'
       }
     }
   })

<ion-view view-title=“TEST”>
  <ion-content>

   <input name="aaa" id="dsds" ng-model="aaa" type="text"/>
        <h3>{{aaa}}</h3>

          <button class="button" ng-click=“test()”>Test</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

   //CONTROLLERS//

$scope.test = function(sql){
    var x = $scope.aaa;
    alert(x);
};
```

In case 2, If I change ng-model =“aaa” with ng-model=“$parent.aaa” then alert gets the values.

So my question is what is the difference between giving controller name in application config section and ng-controller attribute

Thanks

Comment: Both are the same. Maybe you ar placing the function in a wrong location. Where is the $scope.test = function placed? Is it inside the HTML or inside the TestController?

Comment: I think you should read a bit about how javascript prototypal enheritance works. This is a pretty complete article https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Short answer, always have a . in the values you send to ng-model. change your code to something like $scope.a = {aaa:'somevalue'};

Comment: Hi vinagreti, $scope.test definition is in TestController.

Comment: Hi toskv, yes you are right when I define variable as you shown it works.I will read the page you specified whether or not I am missing anything. But interesting thing is that in both cases "<h3>{{aaa}}</h3>" reflects the changes, on the other hand when I try to watch variable in TestController.js with $scope.$watch only case1 works.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Situation only with Ionic. because Ionic is Angular Directive based Framework. All Directive have already self Controller So If you declare **ng-model="aaa"** then it's variable bind with self Controller $scope variable.

You see also Ionic on github and find **.directive('ionView'** you see inside directive already define a Controller. I think This is possible condition.

[Ionic git hub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/driftyco/ionic/master/release/js/ionic.bundle.js)